# How to use the functions of (login / register) and (database CRUD) in the same project in MVC?

Tags: node.js, database, express, model-view-controller

I am now a beginner of the web backend, currently using Node.js and Express.

If I want to write [(login / register) and (database CRUD)], both functions are written in the same project and applied MVC is written so that when executing a project, you can choose to use one of the two functions [(login / register), (database CRUD)].

The teaching I have seen on the Internet are all separate.

The two functions [(Login / Registration) and (Database CRUD)] are not combined in the same project, so I am confused about the combination of the two and apply them at the same time.

The way MVC Framework Application is written, I hope someone can help me answer it, or write a sample program, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create two controllers. One can handle your login information and the other can handle the CRUD.